# Move From one FragmentActivity to other Class?

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have two Classes  name LocationPicker_2 and LocationPicker both are extended with FragmentActivity so I wanted to move from LocationPicker_2 to LocationPicker, I used Simply start activity but it is not working on click.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fte1r.png)

```
 public class LocationPicker_2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback 
{@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_picker2);

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

   from = findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"AIzaSyCIwPlfTKNCGDcoMuOWwNTTyG5tnI_MyqM");
    from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            field = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS,Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
            Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY,field).build(LocationPicker_2.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent,place_picker_req_code);

            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.imageViewbfrom:
                    startActivity(new Intent(LocationPicker_2.this,LocationPicker.class));
                    break;

                case R.id.NexttbtnLP2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(LocationPicker_2.this,Selectdate.class));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Fragment are part of activity. you can't move like this. You can use them on tablayout ,bottomnavgrafh etc.
2. Use Navgraph or tab layout if you want to use fragment